# Multiple choice Data for Moodle database

Tags: database, moodle

Does anyone know where the Moodle multiple choice data is ? like the data of letter A , B , C etc.? because I really want to know where it stores. I hope someone can help me for the Thesis project making.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **(mdl)_qtype_multichoice_options**.

You can find which database tables particular question (or even module) is using inside question subfolder, "db" folder.

See here for example: https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/question/type/multichoice/db/install.xml

EDIT:
My bad, mentioned table points to single, multichoice questions options, not real answers (if that is what you are looking for).

You are looking for **(mdl)_question_answers** (where *mdl_question_anwsers.question* points to *mdl_question.id* (and *mdl_qtype_multichoice_options.questionid*).

Comment: I already look at (mdl)_qtype_multichoice_options.table, but it seems I cant find the DATA of the letters choices. For example a. Apple . I want to access the Data of letter a which is the apple.

Answer (score 0):

After studying the Moodle database for hours, the multiple choice data ,like a. Alpga, b. Bravo etc., are stored in the moodle.mdl_question_answers. Except for the essay type which has a different storage as well.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what exactly you're researching and which technology you're using, but you can easily extract some quiz data from Moodle with R, I use the **moodler** package. If you're connecting to the Moodle database from R, then give it a go. The author is quite responsive, so he may be able to accommodate your requests.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conferences/useR-International-R-User-2017-Conference/moodler-A-new-R-package-to-easily-fetch-data-from-Moodle